# Accessing a file in a different package

Tags: java

I feel like this is a very stupid question, but i've looked for 20 minutes now and i can't for the life of me figure it out, since a lot of online solutions to it seem to not be supported anymore.

How do i get a File object of a file that is in a different package? 
I need it to be a File object because that's what a need to pass on to another method.

I want to test a method that gets an argument of the type File. The file i want to use to test it is in a different package: [puu.sh/8pJAg/b177243091.png](http://puu.sh/8pJAg/b177243091.png) (testdata). I can't seem to access it, i keep getting a filenotfoundexception when i do  `new File("testdata/A000100")`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you show some code and/or examples?

Comment: I want to test a method that gets an argument of the type File. The file i want to use to test it is in a different package: http://puu.sh/8pJAg/b177243091.png
(testdata). I can't seem to access it, i keep getting a filenotfoundexception when i do "new File("testdata/A000100")".

Comment: Use `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` to check whether you are working relative to the correct root directory.

Comment: yes, because you would need full path and that will not work consistently everywhere, check if you cannot use `InputStream` or `Url`, then you could do something like `ResourceAnchor.class.getResourceAsStream("A000100")` assuming package `testdata` contains class `ResourceAnchor`

Comment: or you can create temporary file from resource stream and use that file..

Answer (score 0):

Packages don't contain files, they contain classes and resources.  This is because a package doesn't necessarily exist on the filesystem as a directory (it could be part of a .jar file, or it could be downloaded from a network location via any of several protocols, or it could be generated on the fly by a custom classloader -- Java doesn't actually care).  Your options seem to be:

1. Change the method to accept a stream, and use `Class.getResourceAsStream()`,
2. Copy the stream to a temporary file, call your method, then delete the temporary file once it is finished, or
3. Stop storing the data in a package, and make a directory for it somewhere where you can guarantee it will be present.